# Python Pandas sorting multiindex by column, but retain tree structure

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, tree, multi-index

Using pandas 0.20.3 I am trying to sort the n multilevels of a dataframe by a column ('D') with values (descendlingly) such that the hierarchy of the groups is maintained.

Example input:

```
                    D
A     B     C
Gran1 Par1  Child1  3
            Child2  7
            Child3  2
      Par2  Child1  9
            Child2  2
      Par3  Child1  6
Gran2 Par1  Child1  3
      Par2  Child1  8
            Child2  2
            Child3  3
      Par3  Child1  6
            Child2  8
```

Desired result:

```
                    D
A     B     C
Gran2 Par3  Child2  8
            Child1  6
      Par2  Child1  8
            Child3  3
            Child2  2
      Par1  Child1  3
Gran1 Par1  Child2  7
            Child1  3
            Child3  2
      Par2  Child1  9
            Child2  2
      Par3  Child1  6
```

Solutions to other problems related to sorting and ordering multilevel indices, seem to be focussed on sorting the actual level of the index or maintaining it in order while sorting a column. I did not find a multilevel sort where the values of the columns are used to sort the index by the aggregate value at that specific level. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create three separate arrays and sort by the combination of all them.  In this example, I use Numpy's `np.lexsort` to do the sorting and then I use `iloc` to respect that sort.  At the end, I use `a[::-1]` to get the reverse sort.

```
a = np.lexsort([
    df.D.values,
    df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).D.transform('sum').values,
    df.groupby(level=0).D.transform('sum').values
])

df.iloc[a[::-1]]

                   D
A     B    C        
Gran2 Par3 Child2  8
           Child1  6
      Par2 Child1  8
           Child3  3
           Child2  2
      Par1 Child1  3
Gran1 Par1 Child2  7
           Child1  3
           Child3  2
      Par2 Child1  9
           Child2  2
      Par3 Child1  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`, then [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `sum` values and then  [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['G'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['D'].transform('sum')

df = df.sort_values(['A','G','D'], ascending=False).drop('G',1).set_index(['A','B','C'])
print (df)

                   D
A     B    C        
Gran2 Par3 Child2  8
           Child1  6
      Par2 Child1  8
           Child3  3
           Child2  2
      Par1 Child1  3
Gran1 Par1 Child2  7
           Child1  3
           Child3  2
      Par2 Child1  9
           Child2  2
      Par3 Child1  6
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick, but still not the solution I seek... Note that e.g. within Gran1 the sum within par 1 is larger than the sum in Par3, so should be higher. So sorting should be done in order from levels A to C. Hopefully the explanation makes sense...

Comment: It seems to work on my real dataset... Are you sure the output in your sollution is correct? It does not seem to match your solution. I will try to see if I can extend this for more levels. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does not yet work... it seems to sort on the second col in my dataset but not on the others... Also check different output with desired result

Comment: Thanks! Have to work on my reputation for upvotes I suppose.

Comment: I fear that my provided example was not great. Your solution worked for it, but it does not work on my larger dataset. I have more values for A and these are still messed up... What is the rationale for sorting on A here since sort does not now the 'group loading' at that specific level?

Comment: Hard answer without data. Maybe problem is `sum` values are not unique, so first level is messed. Unfortunately I have no idea for solve it now, becaue problem is data dependent :(

Comment: Suppose names of Gran1 and Gran2 would be the other way around, now sort would get the order of group loadings wrong because it sorts on name. I suppose ascending sort would fail too.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if understand. ButI test it a bit and problem should be if some same sums. e.g. in sample all values in `G` are same (worst dataset). Then output is completely messed. But it messes for me only second `B` level.