# Sorting multiindex by a column while following specific structure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, multi-index

I am using pandas to sort an n level array based on the integers in a column ("D"). It is very important the heirarchy of the groups remain consistent based on the 1st and 3rd level *only*.

I have tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378149/python-pandas-sorting-multiindex-by-column-but-retain-tree-structure/47378196#47378196) where the sort is based on index A and B. However I want to sort based on index A and C as described on the desired output. I have tried using `numpy.lexsort()` to achieve this but the answer in the provided link isn't descriptive of how to function works so I am still quite confused.

```
a = np.lexsort([results.tx.values,
                results.groupby(level=[0,1]).tx.transform('sum').values, 
                results.groupby(level=0).tx.transform('sum').values])
```

This will sort based on the first and second index like in the example link

Example input:

```
                    D
A     B     C
Gran1 Par1  Child1  3
            Child2  7
            Child3  2
      Par2  Child1  9
            Child2  2
      Par3  Child1  6
Gran2 Par1  Child1  3
      Par2  Child1  6
            Child2  2
            Child3  3
      Par3  Child1  6
            Child2  8
```

output I get:

```
                        D
    A     B     C
    Gran2 Par3  Child2  8
                Child1  6
          Par2  Child1  6
                Child3  3
                Child2  2
          Par1  Child1  3
    Gran1 Par1  Child2  7
                Child1  3
                Child3  2
          Par2  Child1  9
                Child2  2
          Par3  Child1  6
```

output I want:

```
                    D
A     B     C

Gran1 Par2  Child1  9  <--
            Child2  2
Gran2 Par3  Child1  6
            Child2  8  <-- 
Gran1 Par1  Child1  3
            Child2  7  <--
            Child3  2
Gran2 Par2  Child1  6  <--
            Child2  2
            Child3  3
      Par1  Child1  4  <--
Gran1 Par3  Child1  2  <--
```

As you can see, I want to highest value from an A+B index pair brought to the top along with all it's children, while keeping other values from the B index separate. It is helpful to keep the children from index C in the same order when  attempting this sort but not necessary. Any help on this problem would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**: I am also looking to do this in reverse order so that the smallest value from each grandparent index rises to the top. Note that this example is not related to the example above.

Desired Output:

```
                         D
    A     B     C

    Gran1 Par2  Child1  -15  
                Child2  -175  <--
                Child3  -65
    Gran2 Par3  Child1  -77   <--
                Child2   8     
    Gran1 Par1  Child1   3
                Child2   7  
                Child3  -12   <--
    Gran2 Par2  Child1   6    <--
                Child2   2
                Child3   3
          Par1  Child1   12  <--
    Gran1 Par3  Child1   24  <--
```

Output I get:

```
                     D
A     B     C

Gran2 Par3  Child1  -77   <--
            Child2   8     
Gran1 Par2  Child1  -15  
            Child2  -175  <--
            Child3  -65
      Par1  Child1   3
            Child2   7  
            Child3  -12   <--
Gran2 Par2  Child1   6    <--
            Child2   2
            Child3   3
      Par1  Child1   12  <--
Gran1 Par3  Child1   24  <--
```

**Edit2**: Answer to my second question would be `df.iloc[(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).D.transform('min')).argsort().values]` based on Wen-Ben's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need `argsort`

```
df.iloc[(-df.groupby(level=[0,1]).D.transform('max')).argsort().values]
Out[416]: 
                   D
Gran1 Par2 Child1  9
           Child2  2
Gran2 Par3 Child1  6
           Child2  8
Gran1 Par1 Child1  3
           Child2  7
           Child3  2
      Par3 Child1  6
Gran2 Par2 Child1  6
           Child2  2
           Child3  3
      Par1 Child1  3
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! How would I do it in reverse order if I want it from smallest to largest? looks like `.transform('min')` did not work for me

Comment: remove the `-` `df.iloc[(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).D.transform('max')).argsort().values]` @rashb

Comment: @rashb ummm what you actual dataset then

Comment: This solution worked for my example but not my dataset. the smallest values from column D for each grandparent index are ordered -52, -59, -22, -70, -175. Would I need to provide a full output to help give some context?

Comment: I will post it in another comment what the desired output I'm looking for is, please give me a second. I appreciate all the help by the way, thank you!

Comment: Hey @Wen-Ben, I've edited my main post to include a desired output + what I get. Let me know if that makes sense and if you have an idea on how to solve it, thanks!

Comment: @rashb you can do with abs first in your D columns

Comment: @rashb `df.iloc[(df.D.abs().groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('max')).argsort().values]
`

Comment: Hey @Wen-Ben, I actually got my result by changing `.transform("max")` to `.transform("min")` instead (in addition to taking out the minus sign). Thus , my final result is `df.iloc[(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).D.transform('min')).argsort().values]`. Thanks for the help once again :) !